# How to remove private information while creating an executable/DLL file with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I create a DLL project with Visual Studio 2010. When I open `my_project.dll` with Notepad, I find project's path (eg. `D:\Solutions\my_project\my_project_1\lib\Release\my_project.pdb`)

My boss want to remove any private information about the project.

How to remove private information while creating an executable/DLL file?

Comment: Properties > Linker > Debugging > Generate Debug Info = "No"

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [PDB Files: What Every Developer Must Know](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/05/11/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know.aspx).

Anyways, you can use the [/PDBALTPATH (Use Alternate PDB Path)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd998269.aspx) to remove the path to the PDB file.

Comment: John Robbin's blog seems to have gone, but the Wayback Machine has a copy of that page from 2014: https://web.archive.org/web/20160313202157/http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know
(I presume that PDB files haven't changed that much since then, but YMMV.)